# How to convert numbers after caret to superscript with jquery

Tags: jquery, text, superscript

A lot of users on our maths forum enter **n-th power** with **caret symbol**, e.g. `x^(4y)`.

We would like to replace the caret symbol and use superscript instead, wrapping the numbers and variables right after the caret. So that x^(4y) becomes x<sup>(4y)</sup>.

Rules:

1. If there is no bracket behind the caret, only superscript the next
   character.
2. If there is an opening bracket, superscript until the closing bracket.

Here is a [post with different caret versions](http://www.gute-mathe-fragen.de/14099/berechnen-sie-den-inhalt-der-flache-und-das-volumen-und-g-x-x-3?show=14110#a14110).

Of course there are many js-libraries out there that we could use, but isn't it possible to do this single text converting task with jquery?

Has anybody build something like that already?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a job for jQuery. Iterating through the text with plain javascript, though verbose, might be the best way to go:

```
function superify(input) {
    if(!input) return input;

    var output = [];
    var buffer;
    for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        var current = input[i];

        if(buffer) {
            if(current === ')') {
                buffer.push('</sup>');
                output.push.apply(output, buffer);
                buffer = null;
            } else {
                buffer.push(current);
            }
        }
        else if(current === '^') {
            var next = input[++i]; 
            if(next === '(') {
                buffer = ['<sup>'];
            } else {
                output.push.apply(output, ['<sup>', next, '</sup>']);
            }   
        } else {
            output.push(current);
        }
    }

    return output.join('');
}
```

(Code not well-tested. Ran it through couple of examples and it seems to have worked)

Comment: Thanks, this is what we needed! Now we can go over all questions and answers and transform the carots ;) to superscript: `$('.answers').each(function() { if ($(this).html().indexOf('^') != -1) { $(this).html( superify(htmlTxt) );  } });`

Last issue: How would you remove the `(` and `)` when superscripting?

Comment: Okay, I think we can remove the brackets with: `if(current === ')') { buffer.pop(); buffer.push('</sup>');` and `if(next === '(') { buffer = ['<sup>', '']; } else {`

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV, changed the code to drop the parens wihout having to modify the buffer.

Comment: while testing I faced one issue: Sometimes we have HTML tags and the text could be: `<b>x</b>^<span>2</span>`. With the current function the `<` gets superscripted and breaks the HTML tags. I tried to use `if(current.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/))` but did not succeed yet to exclude non-numbers and non-letters. Still trying :)

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV, yes, with HTML it gets a bit more complicated. I don't have time to look at it now, but feel free to edit your question and unaccept my answer, if you want to solicit other solutions. Good luck! :)

Comment: Your solution is great, and helped a lot! I will try to edit the function to our needs. I think we just preserve the `^` if there is a `<` next. Thank you

Comment: Alright, here is my current solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MBXTG/ However, a last issue remains: superify() does not take `a^123` into account, it superscripts only the first `1` in this case. New question on that opened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833895/how-to-convert-successive-numbers-after-caret-to-superscript-with-jquery